# Java VM fails with heap size increase

Tags: java, jvm

S0 the command I am trying to run is;

```
java -jar -Xmx290G  /ibers/ernie/home/thh32/rumenISPG/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar  -T VariantFiltration -R Contigs_1.fa  -V Rank10_clean.fasta.gz.Contig_1-sort.bam.vcf1.vcf  --filterExpression "QD < 2.0 || FS > 60.0 || MQ < 40.0 || HaplotypeScore > 13.0 || MappingQuality RankSum < -12.5 "  --filterName "testing_filter"  -o filtered_snps.vcf
```

The machine I am running it on has access to 500G RAM so shouldnt be an issue, however I keep getting this error message;

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 9502720KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 304087040KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so did you resolve it?

Oh also just incase people wonder why I am giving this program so much memory, when I didnt I got this message which indicates that it needs more RAM. This was with 100G heaps size.

```
INFO  09:55:57,953 HelpFormatter - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO  09:55:57,955 HelpFormatter - The Genome Analysis Toolkit (GATK) v3.4-46-gbc02625, Compiled 2015/07/09 17:38:12 
INFO  09:55:57,956 HelpFormatter - Copyright (c) 2010 The Broad Institute 
INFO  09:55:57,956 HelpFormatter - For support and documentation go to http://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk 
INFO  09:55:57,961 HelpFormatter - Program Args: -T VariantFiltration -R Contigs_1.fa -V Rank10_clean.fasta.gz.Contig_1-sort.bam.vcf1.vcf --filterExpression QD < 2.0 || FS > 60.0 ||
 MQ < 40.0 || HaplotypeScore > 13.0 || MappingQuality RankSum < -12.5  --filterName testing_filter -o filtered_snps.vcf 
INFO  09:55:57,967 HelpFormatter - Executing as thh32@node011 on Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 amd64; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_40-b26. 
INFO  09:55:57,968 HelpFormatter - Date/Time: 2015/10/27 09:55:57 
INFO  09:55:57,968 HelpFormatter - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO  09:55:57,969 HelpFormatter - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
INFO  09:55:58,474 GenomeAnalysisEngine - Strictness is SILENT 
##### ERROR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
##### ERROR A USER ERROR has occurred (version 3.4-46-gbc02625): 
##### ERROR
##### ERROR This means that one or more arguments or inputs in your command are incorrect.
##### ERROR The error message below tells you what is the problem.
##### ERROR
##### ERROR If the problem is an invalid argument, please check the online documentation guide
##### ERROR (or rerun your command with --help) to view allowable command-line arguments for this tool.
##### ERROR
##### ERROR Visit our website and forum for extensive documentation and answers to 
##### ERROR commonly asked questions http://www.broadinstitute.org/gatk
##### ERROR
##### ERROR Please do NOT post this error to the GATK forum unless you have really tried to fix it yourself.
##### ERROR
##### ERROR MESSAGE: There was a failure because you did not provide enough memory to run this program.  See the -Xmx JVM argument to adjust the maximum heap size provided to Java
##### ERROR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: are you sure you are running 64 bit JVM?

Comment: @sharonbn `Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 amd64; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server`

Comment: well, the message says it fails to allocate about 9G, so you can try with -Xmx250G. also, maybe there is another process running that allocating lots of RAM? what is `free -h` giving you?

Comment: We use qsub for jobs so I know that these jobs are failing after reaching the heap limit, also because we use qsub I dont think `free -h` will work

Comment: It's complaining about the parallel garbage collector. Try restricting the number of parallel threads in the garbage collector and see if it has any effect - `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2` or try disabling the parallel garbage collector completely - `-XX-UseParallelGC`.

Comment: what java version are you running? you are invoking an old GC engine. the newest one is G1 which is the default in Java 8 and should be the most efficient in footprint and performance terms. you can specify `-XX:+UseG1GC` to order the JVM to use it

Comment: see Oracle documentation for more GC setting options (threads, gen ratio, etc)  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: Ok I tried `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2` which caused the error `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to allocate 9502720KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 304087040KB heap.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.` then I tried `-XX-UseParallelGC` which caused `Unrecognized option: -XX-UseParallelGC
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Comment: and just tried `-XX:+UseG1GC` to get the error ` There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 49849856 bytes for AllocateHeap`

Comment: The correct syntax is `-XX:-UseParallelGC`. Note the colon.